# How to determine that classes do not equal each other

Tags: python, oop

I am unsure how to determine that classes that inherit from other classes are not equal.

I have tried using isinstance to do this but I am not very well versed in this method.

```
class FarmAnimal:

    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({})".format(self, self.age)
```

```
from src.farm_animal import FarmAnimal
class WingedAnimal(FarmAnimal):

    def __init__(self, age):
        FarmAnimal.__init__(self, age)

    def make_sound(self):
        return "flap, flap"
```

```
from src.winged_animal import WingedAnimal

class Chicken(WingedAnimal):

    def __init__(self, age):
        WingedAnimal.__init__(self, age)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.age == other.age:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def make_sound(self):
        return WingedAnimal.make_sound(self) + " - cluck, cluck"
```

```
from src.chicken import Chicken
from src.winged_animal import WingedAnimal

class Duck(WingedAnimal):

    def __init__(self, age):
        WingedAnimal.__init__(self, age)



    def make_sound(self):
        return WingedAnimal.make_sound(self) + " - quack, quack"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Duck):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.age == other.age


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(Chicken(2.1) == Duck(2.1))
```

So in the main method it says to print(Chicken(2.1) == Duck(2.1)) and it prints True, but because they are different classes, I want it to return False.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're only doing an `isinstance()` check in `Duck` but not in `Chicken`. The chicken object is just comparing age. It's agnostic to the type, which is the cause of your error.

Comment: Wow thank you I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: have you tried `print(Duck(2.1) == Chicken(2.1))` you should notice that the eq method called is that of the left hand side. since in your example chicken is first it will use the chicken eq method call and that only checks age not instance

Answer (score 2):

You can define your `__eq__` method in `FarmAnimal`, checking if the class of `self` is the same as the class of `other` as well:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.age == other.age and self.__class__ == other.__class__
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and you don't have to write specific `__eq__` methods in your subclasses.